# How to get UIPath to type into a specific point in a window?

Tags: rpa, uipath

I'm trying to use UIPath to automate some gruntwork in Adobe Premiere, which includes typing in a specific text field.  The problem is, UIPath doesn't recognize that text field as its own element.  It recognizes the window the text field is in as an element, which led me to try using an anchor, which didn't work.  Then I saw the image recording option, and tried that, and I was able to click the text field but not type into it.  Am I doing something wrong?  (I'm sure I am, since usually when I have this kind of programming problem it's because I'm doing something wrong.)  And what can I do to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: You are doing right my friend. Indeed some windows are not able to be  used by element selectors.Instead use the image click activity. As I do not have your software I cannot create a working example for you. Why the image click doesn't work? Did you set it on the correct position?

Comment: Image click does work.  It's when I try to type that it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there some similar tool with same issue that is free to use. Would love to help you on a working example.

Comment: I don't know.  I could take a picture of the screen in question and point out where I'd like to be typing?

Comment: Sure you could do that, but I still cannot test an image. But yeah do that and maybe I have an idea.

Comment: Have you tried comouter vision? That is the best option you have got when working with the image

Answer (score 0):

You might find that Computer Vision does the trick for recognizing the Element.

Or check your properties to ensure that "Click Before Typing" to Enabled on your Type Into Activity. You could also play about with the "Input Mode" as it could be related.

If it's a variable you are passing in to be typed, then add a quick log message before just to ensure that the variable is definitely being set.